# I am trying to add an accordion but its not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

### Accordion is not opening on clicking upon the button.

please help.

### many thanks!

please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:
please find code written below:

### please find code written below:

```js
< script >
  document.querySelectorAll("accordion__button").forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const accordionContent = button.nextElementSibling;
      button.classList.toggle("accordion__button--active");
      if (button.classList.contains("accordion__button--active")) {
        accordionContent.style.maxHeight = accordionContent.scrollHeight + 'px';
      } else {
        accordionContent.style.maxHeight = 0;
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

```css
.accordion__button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  transition: background 0.2s;
}

.accordion__button::after {
  content: '\25be';
  float: right;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.accordion__button--active {
  background: #555555;
}

.accordion__button--active::after {
  content: '\25be';
}

.accordion__content {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <button type="button" class="accordion__button">FUP Plans</button>
  <div class="accordion__content">
    <p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script>  document.querySelectorAll("accordion__button").forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                const accordionContent = button.nextElementSibling;
                button.classList.toggle("accordion__button--active");
                if (button.classList.contains("accordion__button--active")) {
                    accordionContent.style.maxHeight = accordionContent.scrollHeight + 'px';
                }
                else {
                    accordionContent.style.maxHeight = 0;
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

```css
.accordion__button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    transition: background 0.2s;
}

.accordion__button::after {
    content: '\25be';
    float: right;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.accordion__button--active {
    background: #555555;
}

.accordion__button--active::after {
    content: '\25be';
}

.accordion__content {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
        <button type="button" class="accordion__button">FUP Plans</button>
        <div class="accordion__content" >
            <p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia
 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: If you are having a problem with English, please use Google translator to write out your question then paste it into the question section. We don't know what you are trying to solve. No one has time to figure out what you are doing and fix it. Be precise with what you think the problem is and what did you do to try and solve it yourself.

Comment: Did you import the bootstrap and jquery js files?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this modified line.

```
  document.querySelectorAll(".accordion__button").forEach(button => { ... });
```

just add the '.' character to define the classname of the element.

Comment: Thanks buddy you have eagle's eyes, its working fine now.
This "." gave me nightmare.